# iOS Swift JavaScriptCore Performance Optimization

Tags: ios, swift, javascriptcore

I am working on an iOS using Swift 2 and JavaScriptCore. While timer profiling my app, I found these JavaScriptCore methods got called a lot and took most of the time. Is there a way to optimize it?

What can I do to decrease the call of these methods below? For example, JSLockHolder seems to be useless for me since all my JavaScriptCore related function will be called in one thread.

- Running Time                           Symbol                Name
- 18448.0ms 50.6%    valueToArray(OpaqueJSContext*, OpaqueJSValue const*, OpaqueJSValue const**)
- 18087.0ms 49.6%  containerValueToObject(OpaqueJSContext*, JSContainerConvertor::Task)
- 12007.0ms 32.9% valueToObjectWithoutCopy(OpaqueJSContext*, OpaqueJSValue const*)
- 9488.0ms 26.0%    JSC::JSLockHolder::~JSLockHolder()

Comment: Can you describe what you're doing at a high level?

Comment: @DougRichardson I am evaluating the performance of JavaScriptCore in iOS 8+. I have block functions defined in Swift (native) and they were bound  to functions in the `JSContext`. So I can use the same `JSContext` to evaluate script loaded from .js files. When I am profiling, I found these methods consume a lot CPU, seems to be overhead. I am wondering if there are things I can do to avoid these overhead. Or got an confirmation I can not do anything with above methods. These methods seems to be related to passing parameters between JSContext and Native (Swift) world. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @DougRichardson here are [a gist I created as an example](https://gist.github.com/zwang/82632b0fec7897997902)